# Aeroo Report Function not Call in OpenERP

Tags: python, xml, odoo, reportlab, rml

I'm work with Aeroo report in OpenERP. I define function called **fill_stars(self, amount):** which takes the amount and convert into text format.

While I'm going to print report, it gives following error

```
Exception: (u'Aeroo Reports: Error while generating the report "Invoice Report".', UndefinedError('"fill_stars" not defined',))
```

I check the track-back and the result is that "function is not called".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After long time, I found solution. Hope this will helpful to all.

If your Libreoffice server and telnet server is not start than your function will not call.

**Step to start above server.**

```
cd /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/ #to move to the libreoffice:

./soffice -nologo -nofirststartwizard -headless -norestore -invisible "-accept=socket,host=localhost,port=8100,tcpNoDelay=1;urp;" #Open Libreoffice server

telnet localhost 8100 #Open another terminal and Test Localhost
```

And than Go to **Settings/ Modules / Update module list** : Search for  '**ooo**' , you will find '**report_aeroo_ooo**'. Install the module.

And Finally, Configure OpenOffice.org connection from **Setting/Technical/Configure OpenOffice.org co..** and press connect.

After do that, my function and report work well.